# How to create a notification system for new API responses for a telegram bot?

Tags: python, loops, notifications, bots

I have been struggling to build a Telegram bot for a week that informs users whenever there is something new from the API response. Unfortunately, I am constantly getting bogged down when I use a loop to retrieve user preferences from the SQLite3 database and send alerts to users in one-hour intervals. It is not showing me any error messages, although it is not working as expected. Is there anyone who can help me with that?

```
import asyncio
import logging
from telegram import Update, ForceReply, Bot
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    MessageHandler,
    filters,
)

async def notify_issues(bot: Bot):
    # Notify new issues
    while True:
        rows = get_repo() 
        for row in rows:
            user_id, repo_name, repo_owner = row[0], row[1], row[2]
            final_issue = get_issues(repo_name, repo_owner)

            await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=final_issue, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
            
        await asyncio.sleep(60 * 15)  # Wait 15 minutes before checking again
def main() -> None:
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Application and pass it bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    # Command Handler
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # Message Handler
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, process_message))

    # Run codeRadar!
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    asyncio.run(notify_issues(bot))
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I assume that the infinite while loop has caused this, but I have not any other option to do what I want.